# How to make SCONS update the contents of a file used in a build

Tags: scons

What's the proper SCONS method for updating the contents of a file that is part of build?

I use SCONS to build a fairly large project.  But for the sake of a simple question, assume it looks like this:

```
env.Program("foo", ["foo.c", "version.c"])
```

Under certain build conditions, it's necessary to update the contents of one of the CPP files in the build with new information - version information actually. In the above example, I would need to modify the contents of "version.c".  I thought I could do this rather nicely with the following example:

```
env.Command(target="version.c", source=[], action=PythonFunctionToUpdateContents)
env.Program("foo", ["foo.c", "version.c"])
```

The PythonFunctionToUpdateContents would use target[0] as the name of the file, open it, look for some specific text, change it, write the changes back to the same file.  Unfortunately, the above sample doesn't work.  SCONS automatically deletes a target file before building it, so my "version.c" file got deleted before it could be updated.

I tried setting the target and source to the same file in the env.Command() call, but that just creates a dependency cycle.

I know that I could solve this by having SCONS generate the ENTIRE version.c file, but that's not suitable since version.c contains a lot of other code that can change as part of normal development.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The usual way to do this is to have a "version.c.in" or "version-in.c" or whatever you like to call it. Modify that and output it to version.c. You would add the "in" file to your version control system, while the version.c file would not be in there. So the result of all this would look as follows:

```
env.Command(target="version.c", source="version-in.c",
            action=PythonFunctionToUpdateContents)
env.Program("foo", ["foo.c", "version.c"])
```

This applies to other build systems too - it is generally a bad idea to have an input file also be an output file. Far better to use an intermediate file to get the job done.

Comment: The example was too simple, perhaps.  My "env.Program()" call is really an external call to a third-party build process that isn't SCONS based.  So I'm trying to get the file modified before I kick their process off.  I do agree - modifying the file in place isn't a good idea.  But I don't have control over that part of the build process.

Comment: The same principle applies though - you have a file that you control that is the template of the input to the external build process. You create a modified copy of your template into the relevant directory before kicking off the external process. Failing that, you could always create an entire copy of the 3rd party build (might not be practical) and modify the files in that copy.

Answer (score 5):

This answer is kinda late to the party, but here it is anyway:

You should use `env.Precious("version.c")`. This prevents the file from being deleted before being built.

You probably also want to use `env.NoClean("version.c")` so that it doesn't get deleted during a clean.

<strike>You COULD use `env.SideEffect` maybe, but that one seems to have a couple weird things about it. I was told on the mailing list to generally not use that one.</strike>

Comment: Update for anyone reading this answer: `env.SideEffect` should be used for when multiple builders will output to the same file (such as maybe a log, a binary file containing a counter, etc); I don't think it would help in this situation. The pairing of `Precious` and `NoClean` would be the "correct" solution.